# removing extra space

Tags: regex, sed

**cat myfile.sql**

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `AA4`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `AT_Card_INSERT_Trigger`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER='root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `AT_Card_INSERT_Trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `card` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
```

The following works as expected and removes the definer clause.

```
sed -e 's/DEFINER=[^*]*\*/\*/' myfile.sql
```

But it does not work with spaces after or before equal to sign. For e.g. if I have a line like this...

```
/*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
```

Then I need a sed statement something like this...

```
sed -e 's/DEFINER\ =\ [^*]*\*/\*/' myfile.sql
```

But there are 2 more possibilites with space (no space before, no space after). It is also possible that there can be more than 1 space before or after "=".
How do I handle it all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to use the Kleene star; it works for spaces too:

```
sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' myfile.sql
```

That handles spaces only.  If you need tabs as well, drop them into the `[ ]` sections too.  If you have an extended sed that knows about `\s` you can get even fancier.

Comment: The single element classes aren't necessary but they're a nice touch to clarify a single space.

Comment: I'm used to the brackets because sed (on the Mac at least) does not have `\s` so I often write `[ \t]` or `[ \t\n\r]`. :)

Comment: There's always `perl -pe` or `sed -E` and `[[:space:]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add `*` (a single space followed by `*`) to match zero or more spaces:

```
sed -e 's/DEFINER *= *[^*]*\*/\*/' myfile.sql
```

If you're on OSX, you could allow for more whitespace than just spaces using this:

```
# OSX
sed -E -e 's/DEFINER[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*[^*]*\*/\*/' myfile.sql
```

and the same will work with GNU **sed(1)** if you use `-r` in place of `-E`:

```
# GNU
sed -r -e 's/DEFINER[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*[^*]*\*/\*/' myfile.sql
```

GNU **sed(1)** also understands `\s` for whitespace:

```
# GNU
sed -r -e 's/DEFINER\s*=\s*[^*]*\*/\*/' myfile.sql
```

Comment: Yours is nicer.  No brackets.

Comment: @Ray: No, your's is nicer because of the brackets :P It is hard to tell the difference between one space and two sometimes, the brackets removes any ambiguity.